# Truncate BigQuery table through spark

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery

Is it possible to truncate Google BigQuery table through Spark/Scala program?

I tried examples of wordcount given on the https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/examples/bigquery-connector-spark-example

But could not find any way to truncate table.

Any insight on this?

Answer (score 0):

The default write disposition in [BigQueryConfiguration](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/blob/master/bigquery/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/hadoop/io/bigquery/BigQueryConfiguration.java) is `WRITE_APPEND`. You need to specify `WRITE_TRUNCATE` for the BigQuery output configuration. So adding this line of code should work:

```
[..]
conf.set(BigQueryConfiguration.OUTPUT_TABLE_WRITE_DISPOSITION_KEY, "WRITE_TRUNCATE")
[..]
```

Comment: Just got a reply on the below thread  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/issues/43